# The computer cannot find the file specified and Win32 error

Tags: selenium

Whenever I try to use Selenium module after pip installing the module it shows this error. I am not able to run my code and it continuously shows this error. It shows Win32 error. It also shows chromedriver executable needs to be in Path.

Comment: Did you just 3rd person answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webdriver-manager package:

pip install webdriver-manager
the code should look like this:

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
The module download driver automatically and store it at known path for selenium. It will solve all of kinda troubles with driver path